# Mysql query display records within a distance less than 100 KM

Tags: mysql

```
I have 2 tables (given sample records):
1> tbl_travel
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  id     | from_loc| from_lat | from_lon |to_loc |  to_lat | to_lon |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  TRV1   | Kolkata |34.44444  | 84.3434  | Dumka |34.44444 | 84.3434|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  TRV2   | Vizag   |30.44222  | 83.3412  | Pune  |35.44345 | 85.3411|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  TRV3   | Challa  |34.5672   | 82.2345  | Pune  |35.44345 | 85.3411|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------

1> tbl_agent_route
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |id|agent_id|from_route|from_lat| from_lon |to_route |to_lat|to_lon|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |1 |2  | Rachi |34.44444  | 84.3434  | Durgapur|34.44444 | 84.3434|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |2 |2  | Srirampuram |30.44222  | 83.3412  | mumbai  |35.44345 | 85.3411|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |3 |1  | Dariyapur  |34.5672   | 82.2345  | Rajgir  |35.44345 | 85.3411|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I need all the travel record whose from location or to location within 100 km radius of a travel agent route(from_route OR to_route) whose agent_id is 2.

Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome! let me know when you post what you have tried so far...

Comment: So what is your problem? What have you try? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I want to add travel to location but How? 
SELECT l.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(fz.`from_lat`) ) * cos( radians( l.`from_lat` ) ) * cos( radians( l.`from_lon` ) - radians(fz.`from_lon`) ) + sin( radians(fz.`from_lat`) ) * sin( radians( l.`from_lon` ) ) ) ) AS distance, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(fz.`to_lat`) ) * cos( radians( l.`from_lat` ) ) * cos( radians( l.`from_lon` ) - radians(fz.`to_lon`) ) + sin( radians(fz.`to_lat`) ) * sin( radians( l.`from_lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance1 FROM tbl_travel as l HAVING (distance < 100 OR distance1 < 100) JOIN tbl_agent_route as fz WHERE fz.agent_id = 2

Comment: Please suggest any solution!!